# How to list even and odd digits from integer inputs

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Okay so my question is how can I display odd and even digits of a single int input not the whole input. This while using "for" or "while" loop and the % modulator. For example, the program ask a user to enter a positive integer and then it would read each digit and list even and odd digits. I was unable to find a method that reads each character except for the .charAt() but I cant make it work. This is my fail attempt. NOTE: I can't use the % modulator because idk any method to read each digit for an int. Please help, thanks.

```
String = userEntry 
int r = userEntry.length() - 1;
System.out.print("The even numbers are ");

int c = 0; // 0 would count as even.
int size = 0;
while (size < r && c < 9)
{
    if (c == userEntry.charAt(size))
    {
        outputFile.print(" " + userEntry.charAt(size));
        System.out.print(" " + userEntry.charAt(size));
        size++;
    }
    else
    {
        c+=2;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: `a % b == a - (a / b) * b` for positive integer `a` and `b`

Comment: hmm okay let me think.... sorry I have never taken java classes before

Comment: why dont you do your homework on your own ?

Comment: you mean like number%2 == number - (number/2)*2??? sorry im lost...

Comment: I was thinking putting it into an if else if else statement... for example  if number %2 == 0 {number = even} else if number == 0 {number = even} else {number = odd} but i don't think it would calculate single digits but the whole input...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you can use the [modulo](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/273783-the-use-of-the-modulo-operator/) operator.

```
public class Main {
    /** http://stackoverflow.com/q/36053971/6077352 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = 123456789;
        while (input > 0) {
            if (input % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(input % 10 + " is even");
            } else {
                System.out.println(input % 10 + " is odd");
            }
            input = input / 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
9 is odd
8 is even
7 is odd
6 is even
5 is odd
4 is even
3 is odd
2 is even
1 is odd
```

Answer (score 0):

An if statement would do the job of deciding whether the number is odd or even. As for the *for* statement, in order to run it through the whole array you would use code like this:

```
for(*variable* = 0; *variable* < userEntry.length; *variable*++)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mod operator gives you the remainder of doing division on an int. 
So any number mod 10 will return the last digit because the remainder of dividing a digit less than 10 is the number itself. So `30%10=0` and `32%10=2`. So you can use the mod to separate the digits.

And then for each digit you want to check if if it is even or odd. even numbers are divisible by 2 so `number%2` should leave no remainder.

You then have to divide your number by 10 to do the same for the tens column and then again for the hundreds column and so on. This should work for you.

```
 while (number>0) {
    if ((number%10)%2==0) {
        System.out.println(number % 10 + "even"); 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(number % 10+ "odd");
    }
number = number / 10;
}
```